# Dynamically cloned form element attributes with JQuery revert on server validation

Tags: html, jquery, laravel, forms

I've been trying to wrap my head around this issue, I cloned a form using jQuery and set the id of the form elements to increment with the clone count. The issue is that after server validation with errors (using Laravel), the id of the elements revert to the initial id - without the count, even the dynamically added class attribute status-off.

```
 $("#container .container:last").clone().eq(0).clone().find(":input").each(function () {
        var newId = this.id + containerCount;

        this.id = newId;
        $(this).addClass('status-off');
        $(this).val("");
    }).end()
    .show().insertAfter(".container:last");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me, turns out I am iterating the old form components with `@foreach (old('input') ?? ['once'])) as $origin`.
Funny  how I expected the DOM to retain dynamically created attributes.